# translate language of text locally

Tags: python, linux, nltk

Does anyone know of anyway to translate text in a given language to another language at a linux/unix command line?  At the moment I'm most interested in western languages.

I'd prefer not to send anything external to a service such as google translate or babelfish due to volume and firewall constraints.

For me tools close at hand are `python`, `nltk`, `java/jvm` stack, `wordpress`, (locally), pretty much anything `hadoop` or `open source`.

Although I'd hate to attempt to write something to do this, I'm considering maybe just mapping two dictionaries together and then using that to look up tokens singularly.  This obviously wouldn't be the best "translation" but might give me some data I could work with in the desired language... the caveats being words that don't exist verbatim in the desired language, etc.

Comment: Of course, there is [an offline version of Google Translate](https://support.google.com/translate/answer/6142473?hl=en) for Android.

Comment: I normally hate people who say "don't reinvent the wheel" but seriously, don't reinvent the wheel with this.

Comment: Also, there is some [open source machine translation software](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=open+source+machine+translation&oq=open+source+machine+trans&gs_l=hp.3.0.0l2j0i22i30l8.605.3472.0.4430.26.13.0.1.1.0.333.2109.0j2j2j4.8.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..18.8.1950.0.6y-7pwsu49M) that may be useful in this situation.

Comment: @Krythic does "don't reinvent the well" mean you are suggesting I concede on the requirement of using a online service?

Comment: @AndersonGreen thanks, that page was useful.

Comment: @joefromct Yes, or something else. Just don't try to implement this though your own coding. It likely took years to develop what you can find online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what I may have been looking for was `apertium`.  It seems to have packages for install for various linux distributions, and should be accessible through the command line.

http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for. I may have to keep that one in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the dictd server and whatever dictionaries you would like to install. Example of command line syntax to translate English to French after installing dictd would be:

```
dict -d fd-eng-fra "This is a test of the software"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm trying to get it to work at the moment. Sort of tuff to find the server packages for redhat/centos but it seems promising.

Comment: I'm going to have to give up on `dict` and `dictd-server`... as the dictionary for English to Spanish seems very limited... I got it [here](http://www.freedict.org/en/).  For instance, the dict query above shows:
`No definitions found for "This is a test of the software"`.  It seems to missing many many words.